# calling a UIActivity ViewController in SKScene

Tags: swift

I created a game in Sprite Kit using swift and I am at the point where I would like to implement a 'share' button, where when you press it the Activity View Controller pops up and let you decide how you would like to share something.

In the share, a screenshot needs to be taken and a standard text needs to be added. So far I came up with this next code, however I need to call this in a SKScene. This code only allows me to call it while I'm in a ViewController. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
let textToShare = "Swift is awesome!  Check out this website about it!"

    if let myWebsite = NSURL(string: "http://www.codingexplorer.com/")
    {
        let objectsToShare = [textToShare, myWebsite]
        let activityVC = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: objectsToShare, applicationActivities: nil)

        //New Excluded Activities Code
        activityVC.excludedActivityTypes = [UIActivityTypeAirDrop, UIActivityTypeAddToReadingList]
        //

        self.presentViewController(activityVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

As `UIActivityViewController` is called on `ViewController` you have to create a method in `ViewController` presenting the `UIActivityViewController`. Then on the scene call this method.